# Reference Error in Android emulator while working with javascript (sencha touch) in phonegap

Tags: javascript, android, android-emulator, cordova, sencha-touch

I'm trying to test my app with different screen resolutions.

Best and cheapest way to do so is with the emulator, so I tried to launch the app in the emulator. This causes to a problem, which doesn't occur in google chrome and doesn't occur on the device:

`07-07 06:53:12.954: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(279): file:///android_asset/www/lib/ext.util.md5.js: Line 1 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
07-07 06:53:12.954: ERROR/Web Console(279): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext at file:///android_asset/www/lib/ext.util.md5.js:1
07-07 06:53:13.034: DEBUG/PhoneGapLog(279): file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js: Line 1 : ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext
07-07 06:53:13.034: ERROR/Web Console(279): ReferenceError: Can't find variable: Ext at file:///android_asset/www/app/app.js:1`
(and so on)

I'm using PhoneGap 0.9.6 and Sencha Touch 1.1.0 and I don't know why this isn't working because there is no error on device and in the browser.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a link to a possible solution.  It seems to have worked for some but didn't for me.
https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/phonegap/9smqsIVpmiU

Basically increase the timeout time since the emulator takes to long to initialize.  I'm useing 1.0rc1 of phonegap and setting the timeout value doesn't seem to stick.

Comment: Me either.  I've confirmed that it just doesn't work when targeting 2.2.  Seems to work in 2.3.  Tried on 2 different computers.

Comment: It won't work with the 2.2 emulator - can confirm it works with 2.3.3.